# Pandas - unstack column values into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I am storing a lot of redundant values that are making it hard to handle my data. I have a dataframe of the form:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["a","g","n1","y1"], ["a","g","n2","y2"], ["b","h","n1","y3"], ["b","h","n2","y4"]], columns=["meta1", "meta2", "name", "data"])

>>> df

  meta1 meta2 name data
    a     g   n1   y1
    a     g   n2   y2
    b     h   n1   y3
    b     h   n2   y4
```

where I have the names of the new columns I would like in `name` and the respective data in `data`.

I would like to produce a dataframe of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a","g","y1","y2"], ["b","h","y3","y4"]], columns=["meta1", "meta2", "n1", "n2"])

>>> df

meta1 meta2  n1  n2
  a     g  y1  y2
  b     h  y3  y4
```

The columns called `meta` are around 15+ other columns that contain most of the data, and I don't think are particularly well suited to for indexing. The idea is that I have a lot of repeated/redundant data stored in `meta` at the moment and I would like to produce the more compact dataframe presented.

I have found some similar Qs but can't pinpoint what sort of operations I need to do: pivot, re-index, stack or unstack, etc.?

PS - the original index values are unimportant for my purposes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Question I think is related:**

I think the following Q is related to what I am trying to do, but I can't see how to apply it, as I don't want to produce more indexes.

- [Python Pandas- how to unstack a pivot table with two values with each value becoming a new column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665261/python-pandas-how-to-unstack-a-pivot-table-with-two-values-with-each-value-beco)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you group your meta columns into a list then you can do this:

```
metas = ['meta1', 'meta2']

new_df = df.set_index(['name'] + metas).unstack('name')
print new_df

            data    
name          n1  n2
meta1 meta2         
a     g       y1  y2
b     h       y3  y4
```

Which gets you most of the way there.  Additional tailoring can get you the rest of the way.

```
print new_df.data.rename_axis([None], axis=1).reset_index()

  meta1 meta2  n1  n2
0     a     g  y1  y2
1     b     h  y3  y4
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index=['meta1','meta2'], 
                      columns='name', 
                      values='data', 
                      aggfunc='first')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  meta1 meta2  n1  n2
0     a     g  y1  y2
1     b     h  y3  y4
```

But better is use `aggfunc` `join`:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index=['meta1','meta2'], 
                      columns='name', 
                      values='data', 
                      aggfunc=', '.join)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  meta1 meta2  n1  n2
0     a     g  y1  y2
1     b     h  y3  y4
```

Explanation, why `join` is generally better as `first`:

If use `first`, you can lost all data which are not first in each group by `index`, but `join` concanecate them:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["a","g","n1","y1"], 
                   ["a","g","n2","y2"], 
                   ["a","g","n1","y3"], 
                   ["b","h","n2","y4"]], columns=["meta1", "meta2", "name", "data"])

print (df)
  meta1 meta2 name data
0     a     g   n1   y1
1     a     g   n2   y2
2     a     g   n1   y3
3     b     h   n2   y4

print (df.pivot_table(index=['meta1','meta2'], 
                      columns='name', 
                      values='data', 
                      aggfunc='first')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
  meta1 meta2    n1  n2
0     a     g    y1  y2
1     b     h  None  y4

print (df.pivot_table(index=['meta1','meta2'], 
                      columns='name', 
                      values='data', 
                      aggfunc=', '.join)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  meta1 meta2      n1  n2
0     a     g  y1, y3  y2
1     b     h    None  y4
```

Comment: what I have called `meta` is actually multiple other columns.

Comment: Sorry, column `meta` is not one, but more columns like `meta1`, `meta2`... ?

Comment: Great answer as always @jezrael

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: `aggfunc='first'` is brilliant for text data!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#):

```py
new_df = (
    # Actual pivoting.
    df.pivot(
        index=['meta1', 'meta2'],
        columns='name',
        values='data'
    )
    # Remove the column name that pandas adds.
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    # Put back the new index as columns.
    .reset_index()
)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  meta1 meta2  n1  n2
0     a     g  y1  y2
1     b     h  y3  y4
```

I'm using `pandas` version `1.5.3`.