# Python Pandas Unstacking Unique Column Values to Columns Of Their Own

Tags: python, pandas, text, grouping

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['label1', 'label1', 'label2', 'label2',
          'label3', 'label3', 'label4'],
 'Col2': ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'q']}, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

Looks like this

```
     Col1 Col2
0  label1    a
1  label1    d
2  label2    b
3  label2    e
4  label3    c
5  label3    f
6  label4    q
```

For the unique values in `Col1`, I want to turn a column's unique values into columns. In a sense, I'm trying to "unstack" `Col1` values to be column headers and the row values would be the values in `Col2`. My key main issue is that I'm not computing any numeric data - it's all text - and I'm simply trying to reshape the structure.

Here's the desired result:

```
  label1 label2 label3 label4
0      a      b      c      q
1      d      e      f    NaN
```

I've tried: `stack`, `unstack`, `pd.melt`, `pivot_table`, `pivot`.

This ALMOST gets me there, but not quite, and doesn't seem very concise:

```
df.groupby('Col1').apply(lambda x: x['Col2'].values).to_frame().T

Col1  label1  label2  label3 label4
0     [a, d]  [b, e]  [c, f]    [q]
```

[This question shows how to do it with a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns).. but the numeric index in my case is not something I care about.

[This question shows how to also do it with a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840043/pandas-unstack-column-values-into-new-columns).. using aggfunc `first` or `' '.join` but that returns CSV instead of values on respective rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for creating column for new `index` and then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregating `join`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount()

print (df.pivot_table(index='g', columns='Col1', values='Col2', aggfunc=''.join))
Col1 label1 label2 label3 label4
g                               
0         a      b      c      q
1         d      e      f   None
```

Thank you for comment [`Jeff L.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127927/python-pandas-unstacking-unique-column-values-to-columns-of-their-own#comment63687641_38128039):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount()

print (df.pivot(index='g', columns='Col1', values='Col2'))
Col1 label1 label2 label3 label4
g                               
0         a      b      c      q
1         d      e      f   None
```

Or:

```
print (pd.pivot(index=df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount(),
                columns=df['Col1'], 
                values=df['Col2']))

Col1 label1 label2 label3 label4
0         a      b      c      q
1         d      e      f   None
```

Comment: You can also replace the `pivot_table` here with `df.pivot(index='g', columns='Col1', values='Col2')` and get the same result in a slightly shorter line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `set_index` and `unstack`, you could do

```
In [17]: df.set_index([df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount(), 'Col1'])['Col2'].unstack()
Out[17]:
Col1 label1 label2 label3 label4
0         a      b      c      q
1         d      e      f   None
```

---

Details

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
     Col1 Col2
0  label1    a
1  label1    d
2  label2    b
3  label2    e
4  label3    c
5  label3    f
6  label4    q
```