# python pivot table of counts

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe df as follows:

```
| id | movie | value |
|----|-------|-------|
| 1  | a     | 0     |
| 2  | a     | 0     |
| 3  | a     | 20    |
| 4  | a     | 0     |
| 5  | a     | 10    |
| 6  | a     | 0     |
| 7  | a     | 20    |
| 8  | b     | 0     |
| 9  | b     | 0     |
| 10 | b     | 30    |
| 11 | b     | 30    |
| 12 | b     | 30    |
| 13 | b     | 10    |
| 14 | c     | 40    |
| 15 | c     | 40    |
```

I want to create a 2X2 pivot table of counts as follows:

```
| Value | count(a) | count(b) | count ( C ) |
|-------|----------|----------|-------------|
| 0     | 4        | 2        | 0           |
| 10    | 1        | 1        | 0           |
| 20    | 2        | 0        | 0           |
| 30    | 0        | 3        | 0           |
| 40    | 0        | 0        | 2           |
```

I can do this very easily in Excel using Row and Column Labels. How can I do this using Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done this way with Pandas' basic `pivot_table` functionality and aggregate functions (also need to `import NumPy`). See the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840079/4057186) and Pandas [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) documentation with examples:

```
import numpy as np
df = ...
ndf = df.pivot_table(index=['value'],
                     columns='movie',
                     aggfunc=np.count_nonzero).reset_index().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(ndf)

      value id      
movie        a  b  c
0         0  4  2  0
1        10  1  1  0
2        20  2  0  0
3        30  0  3  0
4        40  0  0  2
```

Answer (score 10):

By using `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['value'],df['movie'])
Out[24]: 
movie          a        b        c     
value                            
0              4        2        0
10             1        1        0
20             2        0        0
30             0        3        0
40             0        0        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are familiar with pivot tables in Excel, I'll give you the Pandas `pivot_table` method also:

```
df.pivot_table('id','value','movie',aggfunc='count').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
movie     a        b        c     
value                             
 0             4        2        0
 10            1        1        0
 20            2        0        0
 30            0        3        0
 40            0        0        2
```